# Rectangle overlapping, but saying it's inside?

Tags: java, javafx

I have made a program where the user creates two custom rectangles with CenterX and CenterY coordinates, width and height. After the user specifies these dimensions, the program will display whether or not one rectangle contains the other, overlaps the other, or do not meet at all. Here is my code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.shape.*;
import javafx.scene.text.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import java.util.*;

public class TwoRectangles extends Application
{
   public void start(Stage stage)
   {
       Pane pane = new Pane();

       Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.print("Enter the X and Y center coordinates for rectangle1: ");
       double xCord1 = input.nextDouble();
       double yCord1 = input.nextDouble();

       System.out.print("Enter the Width and Height for rectangle1: ");
       double width1 = input.nextDouble();
       double height1 = input.nextDouble();

       System.out.print("Enter the X and Y center coordinates for rectangle2: ");
       double xCord2 = input.nextDouble();
       double yCord2 = input.nextDouble();

       System.out.print("Enter the Width and Height for rectangle2: ");
       double width2 = input.nextDouble();
       double height2 = input.nextDouble();

       Rectangle rectangle1 = new Rectangle(xCord1, yCord1, width1, height1);
       Rectangle rectangle2 = new Rectangle(xCord2, yCord2, width2, height2);

       rectangle1.setFill(null);
       rectangle2.setFill(null);
       rectangle1.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
       rectangle2.setStroke(Color.BLACK);

    // Compute the 4 corners's coordinates for the rectangle
        double r1x1 = xCord1 - (width1 / 2.0);
        double r1x2 = xCord1 + (width1 / 2.0);
        double r1y1 = yCord1 + (height1 / 2.0);
        double r1y2 = yCord1 - (height1 / 2.0);

        double r2x1 = xCord2 - (width2 / 2.0);
        double r2x2 = xCord2 + (width2 / 2.0);
        double r2y1 = yCord2 + (height2 / 2.0);
        double r2y2 = yCord2 - (height2 / 2.0);


   if ((r1x1 >= r2x1) && (r1x2 <= r2x2) && (r1y1 >= r2y1) && (r1y2 <= r2y2))
      { 
         Text containText = new Text(500, 500, "One rectangle is contained in another");
         pane.getChildren().add(containText);
      }

    else if ((r1x1 < r2x2) && (r1x2 > r2x1) &&  (r1y1 < r2y2) && (r1y2 > r2y1))
       {
            Text overlapText = new Text(500, 500, "The rectangles overlap");
            pane.getChildren().add(overlapText);

       }

       else
       {
            Text noneText = new Text(500, 500, "The rectangles do not overlap");
            pane.getChildren().add(noneText);
       }      
       pane.getChildren().addAll(rectangle1, rectangle2);
       Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
       stage.setTitle("Overlapping Rectangles");
       stage.setScene(scene);
       stage.show();
   }
}
```

Whenever I enter, (50, 50) for centerX and centerY coordinates for both rectangles, width: 20, height 50 for rectangle1, and width 50, height 20 for rectangle2 it tells me that the rectangles are inside each other rather than overlapping each other. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem are the Y-coordinates. The 2nd one is smaller than the first one. This means the tests will become less readable, e.g.

```
(r1x1 >= r2x1) && (r1x2 <= r2x2) && (r1y1 >= r2y1) && (r1y2 <= r2y2)
```

becomes (with also checking if r2 is in r1):

```
(r1x1 >= r2x1 && r1x2 <= r2x2 && r1y1 <= r2y1 && r1y2 >= r2y2) ||
//                                    ^^              ^^
(r2x1 >= r1x1 && r2x2 <= r1x2 && r2y1 <= r1y1 && r2y1 >= r1y2)
```

Comment: I would say that the calculation has a mistake `double r1y1 = yCord1 + (height1 / 2.0);` must be `double r1y1 = yCord1 - (height1 / 2.0);` and similarly `double r1y2 = yCord1 + (height1 / 2.0);` and for r2y1 and r2y2 as well

Comment: @ItachiUchiha usually yes, but when you are drawing stuff it can be better the other way.

Comment: @ItachiUchiha I change my first condition to your condition, but I am still getting the same error

Comment: @bytes you need to change all four of them

Comment: Change all four of them to what?

Comment: @maraca actually you are right as well. It depends on the perspective of the one writing the code..

Comment: @Bytes either change `-` to `+` and vice versa in all `y` calculations or change the comparator in all y comparisons.

Comment: @ItachiUchiha I corrected my formulas and it works for this example, but when I make a rectangle inside a rectangle, it displays that it overlaps instead

Comment: @Bytes as I said, you don't check if r2 is in r1, only if r1 is in r2.